# Activerecord - Sort parent model by child attribute, when child has specific second attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table that displays student test scores. I have these classes:

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tests
end

class Test < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
end
```

The table displays the students' 3 major test scores:

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| Name  | Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| Jeff  |   60.5 |   45.9 |  100.0 |
| Cindy |   50.0 |   99.0 |   88.5 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want to be able to order the students by specific test scores. So I might order desc by the test scores on Test 1 (resulting in `[Jeff, Cindy]`) or Test 2 (resulting in `[Cindy, Jeff]`).

I'm not really sure how to incorporate the test name into the query.

Comment: I think you will need to use pivot table technique for this. Checkout https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/creating-pivot-tables-in-postgresql-using-the-crosstab-function/

Comment: Is a test only for one student?

Comment: @demir correct. A test belongs only to a single student.

Answer (score 1):

`joins` actually by default is `inner join` i.e. it'll remove all students who haven't given a test, and all tests without students.

You can try the below code.

```
# for rails version < 5
Student.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "tests" ON "tests"."student_id" = "students"."id"')
       .where(tests: { id: test1_record_id }).order('tests.score desc')

# for rails version >= 5

Student.left_outer_joins(:tests)
       .where(tests: { id: test1_record_id }).order('tests.score desc')
```

I haven't tested it, but you should get the idea.

EDIT:

You can use the following query:

```
(SELECT students.*, 
        tests.marks, 
        tests.NAME 
 FROM   students 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tests 
                     ON tests.student_id = students.id 
 WHERE  tests.NAME = 'test3' 
 ORDER  BY tests.marks DESC) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT students.*, 
        tests.marks, 
        tests.NAME 
 FROM   students 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tests 
                     ON tests.student_id = students.id 
 WHERE  tests.NAME != 'test3');
```

And execute it like `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query).entries`

Comment: This results in the same problem as the other solution (using `.joins`). Here, my table will only be populated with the Student Name and Test 1 scores. They will be sorted, but the other test scores will be omitted from the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort students like this:

```
Student.joins(:tests).where(tests: { id: test1_record_id }).order('tests.score desc')
```

Comment: It's close, however, the problem here is that students only return with the test scores from the one test specified. I need all tests scores returned with the student, but ordered by that test score.